# web development. Better way to display a page within a page than iframe

Tags: iframe, web

I'm not a web developer. I'm a budding game developer and I'm just making myself a website for my portfolio.

I made [this](http://bam.net16.net/java_bookshop/java_bookshop/) as a little college project. Its just one html page with almost nothing on it. And everything is added to the DOM with javascript (when you go to a new 'page' the last stuff is removed)

For my portfolio site I want to do something similar to this. Where the title / breadcrumbs and so on remain static and the content changes depending what project you want to look at.
In my bookshop example the JS add/remove was convenient cus all the books had the same types of info and it was just stored in a little database like structure.

For my portfolio website each project content bit might have a different layout / info as each project is different. (eg some might be just a video, some might be all text etc.)

So iframe springs to mind but I know that iframes are bad for accessibility and thats something I want to avoid as a general principle.
Any of you web guys have any ideas as to how to load a page (or achieve something similar) into another page without iframe so it is really *part* of its host page and reads that way not just visually but would read properly by a blind person say (I forget the word for this!)

Comment: If you want to display your own site, with your own structure, then a simple DIV can be filled with an AJAX request and it should be OK. But if you are loading a site completely unrelated to you, I don't see other option than an iframe.

Comment: You lost me at "read properly by a blind person" -- this sounds like 508 compliance, which I don't think jives too well with ajax requests which is what I was thinking until then..

Comment: agh! there s a word for this! that I cant remember. Basically with an iframe the site (lets say with no css) will not be in proper order of H1,H2,H3,pargraph  etc. Do you get what T'm saying?

Comment: @ Alejandro.. So is it possible to use javascript to fill a div with the contents from another html page?  Rather than write all custom javascript to make everything.. If so could you point me in the right direction? cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using php to fill a div with the information. You can then store the project content in a separate file from the rest of the page, and it is separated from a markup standpoint as well (which is what I'm guessing your after?)

Note that the user will receive both pages together, its only separate from the server's point of view.

For example (untested):

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="projects">
<? $page = file_get_contents("projects.html"); echo $page; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok cool thanks!! Is that a lot of work though? Will I need server side processing? Like, making a little site with html, css and JS is so handy! Then I can throw it up on any free webhost

Comment: Its not a lot of work, but it does require that the host support php. If you cannot find a free webhost that supports php you are  basically stuck with a JS or html solution.

Comment: Ok I might do that then. I've never seen php. Afterwards I can put it on my CV  :D

Comment: Also the site where that JS project is hosted supports php :)

Comment: Edited answer with a starting point; projects.html would hold your projects page, but remember its only a fragment, not a full page (no html tag).

Comment: Btw you wouldnt happen to know that word for how a webpage should read for accessibility, lets say with no css it should stiil be in the right hierarchical order from top to bottom with H1,H2,H3, paragraph etc. ?? This is killing me!

Comment: I know what your referring to, but I didn't know it was summed up in a single word. I suppose descriptive markup?

Comment: Maybe u never heard it used butThe way the word is used is eg. 'the website should make sense when read &$&^*£*&ally'  ......Its like 'grammatically' or 'syntactically'